# auto mapping c# objects to another format

Tags: c#, .net

I wish to map two C# objects, the objects are complex and nested and they do not have same structures (they do not have same naming convention).

I have used automapper earlier where two objects had same naming convention with the second one having a couple extra fields.

Is there any other option in my new case except creating the second object manually..

Any help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Automapper is not only for mapping by naming convention, it also supports conversion rules, for example in one of my projects i used such a configuration: CreateMap<Measurement, MeasurementDTO>()
                .ForMember(t=>t.MeasuringValueName, opt=>opt.MapFrom(s=>s.ControlledElement.MeasuringValue.Name)).

If you want to map your objects fully manual, create constructors with initial type as parameter

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy : Wow..could you please share a simple version of this code with Measurement, MeasurementDTO structure,Just show createmap for a couple, it should be fine.. Tx

Comment: you'd better provide an example you want to achieve in question, i'll try my best to help you. Sorry, i cannot share my code as it's my company legacy...